# Delete keys of an array if its values exists in previous keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, combinations

```
Array
(
    [0 0 0 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 0
            [1] => 0 1
            [2] => 0 2
            [3] => 0 3
            [4] => 0 4
        )

    [0 1 0 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 1
            [1] => 0 2
            [2] => 0 3
            [3] => 0 4
            [4] => 0 5
        )

    [0 1 4 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 1
            [1] => 1 1
            [2] => 2 1
            [3] => 3 1
            [4] => 4 1
        )

    [0 2 0 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 2
            [1] => 0 3
            [2] => 0 4
            [3] => 0 5
        )

    [0 2 0 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 2
            [1] => 0 3
            [2] => 0 4
            [3] => 0 5
            [4] => 0 6
        )

    [0 3 1 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 3
            [1] => 0 4
            [2] => 1 3
            [3] => 1 4
        )

    [0 3 3 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 3
            [1] => 1 3
            [2] => 2 3
            [3] => 3 3
        )

    [0 3 4 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 3
            [1] => 1 3
            [2] => 2 3
            [3] => 3 3
            [4] => 4 3
        )

    [0 5 1 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 5
            [1] => 0 6
            [2] => 1 5
            [3] => 1 6
        )

    [0 5 4 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 5
            [1] => 1 5
            [2] => 2 5
            [3] => 3 5
            [4] => 4 5
        )

    [0 6 3 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 6
            [1] => 1 6
            [2] => 2 6
            [3] => 3 6
        )

    [0 6 4 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 6
            [1] => 1 6
            [2] => 2 6
            [3] => 3 6
            [4] => 4 6
        )

    [1 0 2 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 0
            [1] => 1 1
            [2] => 2 0
            [3] => 2 1
        )

    [1 1 4 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 1
            [1] => 2 1
            [2] => 3 1
            [3] => 4 1
        )

    [1 1 5 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 1
            [1] => 2 1
            [2] => 3 1
            [3] => 4 1
            [4] => 5 1
        )

    [1 2 5 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 2
            [1] => 2 2
            [2] => 3 2
            [3] => 4 2
            [4] => 5 2
        )

    [1 4 2 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 4
            [1] => 1 5
            [2] => 2 4
            [3] => 2 5
        )

    [1 5 5 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 5
            [1] => 2 5
            [2] => 3 5
            [3] => 4 5
            [4] => 5 5
        )

    [2 1 2 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 1
            [1] => 2 2
            [2] => 2 3
            [3] => 2 4
            [4] => 2 5
        )

    [2 2 2 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 2
            [1] => 2 3
            [2] => 2 4
            [3] => 2 5
        )

    [2 2 2 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 2
            [1] => 2 3
            [2] => 2 4
            [3] => 2 5
            [4] => 2 6
        )

    [2 2 3 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 2
            [1] => 2 3
            [2] => 3 2
            [3] => 3 3
        )

    [2 2 5 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 2
            [1] => 3 2
            [2] => 4 2
            [3] => 5 2
        )

    [2 5 5 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 5
            [1] => 3 5
            [2] => 4 5
            [3] => 5 5
        )

    [3 0 3 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3 0
            [1] => 3 1
            [2] => 3 2
            [3] => 3 3
        )

    [3 0 3 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3 0
            [1] => 3 1
            [2] => 3 2
            [3] => 3 3
            [4] => 3 4
        )

    [3 1 4 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3 1
            [1] => 3 2
            [2] => 4 1
            [3] => 4 2
        )

    [3 4 4 5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3 4
            [1] => 3 5
            [2] => 4 4
            [3] => 4 5
        )

    [4 5 5 6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4 5
            [1] => 4 6
            [2] => 5 5
            [3] => 5 6
        )

)
```

for example this is my multi array, and each keys (0 1 0 5, 0 1 4 1) has their values. I want to make combination set of deleting keys if their values existing in previous key arrays.

For examples: key "0 1 4 1" has value "0 1" which exists in previous key "0 1 0 5" in this case we delete (unset) the 0 1 4 1 . How will I do this for all elements. And make a combinations of size of keys of array. I hope you understand it

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly, you want to remove the entire "0 1 4 1" array because its value "0 1" exists in the "0 1 0 5" array? If that's the case then why wouldn't we remove the "0 1 0 5" array because some of its values exist in the "0 0 0 4" array?

Comment: hello sir, thank you for answer. Yeap, we need to start from 1st array, and go comparing from last to first, if next values has in previous then delete it (Next one). and so go on

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're going for, here's one way to do it by filtering the array of sets with `array_intersect()`. The filter callback should only return true if the intersection of the current set and the previous set is empty.

```
$result = array_filter($sets, function($set) {
    static $previous = [];
    $matches = array_intersect($set, $previous);
    $previous = $set;
    return !$matches;
});
```

---

The code in the first part of the answer shows how to remove every array that has values in common with the preceding single array. If you need to remove sets that have values in common with *any* of the previous arrays, I would do it this way:

```
$result = array_filter($sets, function($set) {
    static $previous = [];
    foreach ($set as $value) {
        if (isset($previous[$value])) $matches = true;
        $previous[$value] = true;
    }
    return empty($matches);
});
```

Comment: thank you sir, you gave me an idea. To use array intersect to compare next and all previous arrays whether they have common values. I will try to use it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Oh, _all_ previous arrays? I misunderstood, I thought you meant only the one directly before.

Comment: yes, need to compare all previous keys, anyways, I will use **array_intersect** functions